# How to add a custom .png file as a Marker for Google Maps in a Android App

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-markers

I have a Activity that displays a map for a Android app using Google Maps and I want to replace the Yellow Marker I am currently using with a ping image that I created called fillingstation.png.  How would I go about doing that as I am fairly new to Android App Development.

MapViewActivity.java

```
 private void showFuelStops(String location) throws IOException{
       Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(this, Locale.getDefault());  
       List<Address> addresses;

       addresses = geocoder.getFromLocationName(location, 1);
       if(addresses.size() > 0) {
          BitmapDescriptor subwayBitmapDescriptor = BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_YELLOW);
          double latitude= addresses.get(0).getLatitude();
          double longitude= addresses.get(0).getLongitude();
          LatLng subLoc = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);
          Marker fuelMarker = map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(subLoc).icon(subwayBitmapDescriptor).title("Subway, " + location));

       }        
 }
```

Comment: You are doing something wrong in your code.

You should never be doing blocking operations on the UI thread and Geocoder.getFromLocationName() is calling webservice.

Comment: Maciej focus I am asking about images.  Besides I am going to need that code later.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If the PNG file is a resource (i.e., it is in `res/drawable-NNNN/` for various densities), use `fromResource()` instead of `defaultMarker()` on `BitmapDescriptorFactory`.

If the PNG file is an asset (i.e., it is in `assets/` in your project), use `fromAsset()`.

If the PNG file is a file on the device's internal storage, use `fromFile()`.

Comment: Ok So I am using the Drawable, so fromResource it is.

Comment: But how do I call the ping file do I have to create a xml for it?

Comment: if your have ping.png in drawable-mdpi (and others): BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.ping)

Comment: When I do the R.drawable. it will not find the .png file in that folder even though it is there.

Comment: Never mind it was a bug with eclipse I had to shut down eclipse and rebuild and it was there.

Comment: BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.id.xyz) is not working for me inside Instant App... where xyz is a png
but luckily BitmapDescriptorFactory.decodeResource works..